# Position absolute element not visible

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add arrows to my slider, but the arrows are not showing on the page, when I refresh the page I can see them for one sec and it disappears - what might be causing this issue?

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -120px;
  z-index: 1111;
}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -120px;
  z-index: 1111;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div>slide</div>
  <img src="prev.svg" class="prev">
  <img src="next.svg" class="next">
</div>
```

Comment: slider as it is takes up 100% of width.  These items will only show if slider has at least 120px of space on either side.  Try setting the `left` and `width` css properties of slider to like `150px` to see the other elements appear.

Answer (score 0):

I put `.main-content` for example. Because `.slider` elements are exceed the screen.

**Edit:** You can change width of `.slider` if you want.

```css
.main-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.slider {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 300px; /* your option */
}

.next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -120px;
    z-index: 1111;
    height: 85px;
    width: 85px;
}

.prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -120px;
    z-index: 1111;
    height: 85px;
    width: 85px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="slider">
        <div>slide</div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png" class="prev">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png" class="next">
    </div>
</div>
```